# Clarifying $L^p$ convergence

Tags: lp-spaces, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

$L^p$ convergence for real valued random vectors is defined as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|X_n-X\|^p]\underset{ n\uparrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0, p\geq 1.
\end{align*}
What norm is typically used in this definition for vectors?

And does this convergence imply convergence of all the moments? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475133/when-does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-of-the-p-th-moment) appears to address the question but seems to implicitly define $L^p$ convergence via the $p$-norm,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|X_n-X\|_p]\underset{ n\uparrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0, p\geq 1.
\end{align*}
instead of a $p$th power of a norm, as above.

Comment: Are the random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Or an infinite-dimension vector space?

Comment: finite dimensional